# How to prove by this type of question by Induction (If $a_1 = 6$ and $a_{m+1} = 2a_m - 3m + 2$ for $m \geq 1$, then $a_n = 2^n + 3n + 1$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Please do not tell me how to prove this exact question. I would like to know how to go about proving the following type of question by induction:

If $a_1 = 6$ and $a_{m+1} = 2a_m - 3m + 2$ for $m \geq 1$, then $a_n = 2^n + 3n + 1$

Again, please do not prove this for me, but show me how to prove questions of this type, perhaps through the use of another example.

I did look at using multidimensional induction, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate, and to be honest, I do not fully understand it.

I would greatly appreciate any help,

Thanks.

Comment: I do not know what is multidimensional induction, but I see nothing special about this problem when you use usual induction, it works just fine. Perhaps just try again? It would be difficult to give an idea without solving it, the problem is solved on just one line, do it one more time.

Comment: perhaps seeing both $n$ and $m$ in the same problem makes it look like it is "multidimensional", but you may replace $a_{m+1} = 2a_m - 3m + 2$ with $a_{n+1} = 2a_n - 3n + 2$ if that helps. It means the same.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, can't believe I didn't spot that! Late nights eh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by proving the base case: $a_{1} = 6$. Is the closed form solution satisfied?

Now assume true up to $k > 1$. And prove true for $k+1$. You will want to use the inductive hypothesis on $a_{m}$ and then some algebraic simplifications.

> > Please do not tell me how to prove this exact question

Um, okay? It would probably be better then for you to pick an example you want to see proven so we can help you push through the steps. We really don't want to come up with different examples if you already have one you are interested in. But the procedure I outlined above is what you want to use (and in general, how weak induction works). If your recurrence is not first-order, you would use strong-induction with the multiple base cases.

Perhaps you will find this tutorial on induction helpful: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/280815-introduction-to-proofs-induction-and-big-o/

Comment: The if, then nature of this question makes me think of implies. Does this mean that I first have to prove that $a_n = 2^n + 3n + 1$, and since $a_{m+1} = 2a_m - 3m + 2$ was given to me, I can assume that it's true, therefore giving me true => true, which is of course true?

Comment: I think I've proved it. I managed to get $a_{k+1} = 2^{k+1} + 3(k+1) + 1$ in the form $a_{k+1} = 2a_k - 3k + 2$.

Comment: Looks good to me. And yes, it is an implication. You take that $a_{k} = 2^{k} + 3k + 1$ and the form of the recurrence given, and use that to derive the closed form expression of $a_{k+1}$.